# Set a radial offset on a polar projection in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have some simulated data in a 2D numpy array with a size like (512, 768).

This data is simulated from rmin = 1 to rmax = 100 and phi from 0 to 2pi

I try to plot this on a polar plot, but without an offset in radial direction this looks really odd. Note: The images are coming from a radial density distribution, so the plotsshould be radial symmetric.

**Without xlim/ylim set:**

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

rho = // 2D numpy array

ax.pcolormesh(rho)
fig.show()
```

[image: Radial plot without offset and xlim/ylim]

**With xlim/ylim set:**

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

rho = // 2D numpy array
print rho.shape

ax.axis([x_scale[0], x_scale[-1], y_scale[0], y_scale[-1]])

ax.pcolormesh(rho)
fig.show()
```

[image: Radial plot without offset]

**With a manual axis + X/Y values.**

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

rho = // 2D numpy array
print rho.shape

ax.axis([x_scale[0], x_scale[-1], 0, y_scale[-1]])
y_scale_with_offset = np.insert(y_scale, 0, 0)

ax.pcolormesh(x_scale, y_scale_with_offset, rho)

ax.pcolormesh(rho)
```

[image]

Is there a trick to add a radial offset from 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use `ax.set_rmin()` with polar plots, a negative value will give you the effect your looking for.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

c = np.ones((50,50)) + np.arange(50).reshape(50,1)

aP = ax.pcolormesh(c)
plt.colorbar(aP)
ax.set_rmin(-10.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

It's worth including a scale so you know your not just removing data from the plot(I assume this is not what you intended).

On a side note, if you haven't already you should check out the [ipython notebook], you may have been able to find the solution to your problem as you can press tab after typing `ax.` and it will pop up a list of all the objects you could use. Since matplotlib is nicely labeled, `set_rmin` is a fairly obvious choice.